# Using Go to make a POST request using a JSON file

Tags: json, go, post

I am very new to Go and searched around for this question but did not find anything, so I apologize if this is a duplicate that I missed.

I need to send a POST request using Go and have the body come from a JSON file. Below is a modified version of the code from https://golangtutorial.dev/tips/http-post-json-go/ that I am using as a starting point.

I am thinking that I can just substitute the `jsonData` var with a JSON file that I pull in but I just wanted to know if this is the correct approach and how to best go about doing this. Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    httpposturl := "https://reqres.in/api/users"

    // I think this is the block I need to alter?:
    var jsonData = []byte(`{
        "name": "morpheus",
        "job": "leader"
    }`)

    request, error := http.NewRequest("POST", httpposturl, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, error := client.Do(request)
    if error != nil {
        panic(error)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", response.Status)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post a file, use the [opened](https://godoc.org/os#Open) file as the HTTP request body:

```
f, err := os.Open("file.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()

httpposturl := "https://reqres.in/api/users"
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", httpposturl, f)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()

fmt.Println("response Status:", response.Status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: whatever(words, file, image, or even video, etc..) you want to post by the http protocol, you post bytes stream in fact. That means you should treat anything you want to post as **an array of binary bytes**.

In your case, you should first open the file you want to post, and creates an instance of type io.Reader which pointes to your file. the simple code as belows:

```
f, _ := os.Open("./my-file")
    
http.Post("https://example.com/api","application/json",f)
```